# Basing ASP.NET Outputcache on querystring parameter AND session

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I would like to know if its possible to use outputcache with a querystring parameter AND a session parameter together.

I'm serving location based content and the countryid is stored in a session, while other parameters as categoryid, pageindex are stored in querystring.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible to vary the Output Caching based on pretty much anything you want by using VaryByCustom, and providing a special function that will return the cache key string.  For your case, try a directive like this:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="30" VaryByParam="myParam" VaryByCustom="mySessionVar" %>
```

Then in Global.asax, override the GetVaryByCustomString function for your application:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if(arg == "mySessionVar" && Session["mySessionVar"] != null)
    {
        return Session["mySessionVar"].ToString();
    }

     return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
}
```

Comment: -1 You can't acess session at this time. "Session state is not available in this context."